# How to check selected value of a radio group using id

Tags: javascript

I've seen many examples in stackoverflow getting the group radio value using input name. Is there any way to find it using id ?

Comment: Using `id`, check what the `name` is and then check the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to use the name as it enables you to know *which* radio button in a group is selected (all radio buttons in a group have the same name but [only one has a given id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)).

But if you want to check whether a particular radio button whose id you have is checked, you can do this :

```
var yesorno = document.getElementById('someId').checked;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6Uv9A/)

If you want to get the value of the radio button whose id you know, it's simply

```
var value = document.getElementById('someId').value;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but i don't want to use name. is there any way to get the value of it using id?

Comment: Having a double appearance of the same id is **BAD** programming. It will only catch the first/last one depending on the browser, it's against the standard and should be avoided at all cost to prevent unknown errors in your code. + You got to have a name otherwise the browser won't treat them as the same group.

Comment: Why the downvote ? @iMoses Who said there should be "double appearance of the same id" ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Weird. Upvoting as there is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: Ok, you've edited. If it's that important to you I'll withdraw the downvote, but as I said, as a long time web developer this was in my opinion a terrible advice and wrong programming.

Comment: @iMoses Look at the history. I **never** wrote there should be  "double appearance of the same id" ! You're just trying to fix imaginary errors.

Comment: Your solution still doesn't give the radio button value, which was the original question.

Comment: You haven't said it, but before adding that it shouldn't that's what was understood from it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, not really.

You got to have a name otherwise the radio buttons will not work together, meaning all of them could be checked. When you already have a name, get the value by:

```
$('[name="myGroup"]:radio:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself. This code worked for me!.

```
alert($('input[id=groudid]:checked').val());
```

Comment: This is simply not what you asked and it's very very wrong : only one input can have a given id.

Comment: There is no downvote on your answer. Please read [the norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) : an id **must** be "unique in a document"

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $("#myId").attr("name")    
$(":radio").filter(function(){return $(this).attr("name") == name}).filter(":checked").val()
```